# Do receivers identify which method to apply?

Tags: go, receiver

A Tour of Go: https://tour.golang.org/methods/9

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type Abser interface {
    Abs() float64
}

func main() {
    var a Abser
    f := MyFloat(-math.Sqrt2)
    v := Vertex{3, 4}

    a = f  // a MyFloat implements Abser
    a = &v // a *Vertex implements Abser

    // In the following line, v is a Vertex (not *Vertex)
    // and does NOT implement Abser.
    a = v

    fmt.Println(a.Abs())
}

type MyFloat float64

func (f MyFloat) Abs() float64 {
    if f < 0 {
        return float64(-f)
    }
    return float64(f)
}

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y float64
}

func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
}
```

In this exercise, there are two `Abs()` methods. But it seems that line 24, `fmt.Println(a.Abs())`, automatically applies the one that has a receiver with the same type as the variable.

Is this a feature of receivers?

Comment: This is all wrong. There are two types and each has _one_ Abs() method and the "feature of the receiver" is how interfaces work. Nothing special here.

Comment: This is not a feature of receivers. Receivers are attached to methods and used when calling those methods upon receivers.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
But one thing I doubt is the use of upvote and downvote, 
is stackoverflow a place to ask questions or a place to gather  correct understanding of issues? hmmmm

Comment: Please check [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @peterSO Thanks for the information well I have not downvoted I have answered OP comment of `is stackoverflow a place to ask questions or a place to gather correct understanding of issue`

Comment: @ShiningGo I doubt *you* misunderstand how upvote/downvote works. I dare say there's something .. smelly .. in the kingdom of the Go tag. Far, far too many question downvotes, non-answers that quote specs instead of asnwering and comments that violate the [Be nice policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). *30 downvotes in a single day!!!!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Method sets](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets)
>
> A type may have a method set associated with it. The method set of an
>   interface type is its interface. The method set of any other type T
>   consists of all methods declared with receiver type T. The method set
>   of the corresponding pointer type *T is the set of all methods
>   declared with receiver *T or T (that is, it also contains the method
>   set of T). Further rules apply to structs containing embedded fields,
>   as described in the section on struct types. Any other type has an
>   empty method set. In a method set, each method must have a unique
>   non-blank method name.
>
> The method set of a type determines the interfaces that the type
>   implements and the methods that can be called using a receiver of that
>   type.

---

> The method set of a type determines the interfaces that the type
>   implements and the methods that can be called using a receiver of that
>   type.

For example, simplifying the Go Tour example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type Abser interface {
    Abs() float64
}

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y float64
}

func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
}

func main() {
    var a Abser
    a = &Vertex{3, 4} // a *Vertex implements Abser
    fmt.Println(a.Abs())
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/cf3WMcBI0WJ

Output:

```
5
```

Variable `a` of type `Abser` can contain any variable type that has the `Abser` method set : `Abs() float64`. Variable `a` contains a `*Vertex` which satisfies `Abser` with method set `func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64`. The expression `a.Abs()` executes the method `Abs()` for the type `*Vertex` that it currently contains.